# Wordpress different layout of related articles

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying 3 columns layout of related articles, but if the number of related articles is less than 3 to be different layout. If the number of related articles is 2 the first column to have class `col-sm-offset-2`, and if the columns is 1 - to have class `col-sm-offset-4`.

```
$category        = get_post_category();
$relatedArticles = get_posts( [
    'exclude'        => $post->ID,
    'category'       => $category->term_id,
    'posts_per_page' => 3
] );
?>
<?php if ( count( $relatedArticles ) > 0 ): ?>
    <section class="related-articles">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo __( 'Related Articles' ) ?></h2>
                <?php foreach ( $relatedArticles as $relatedArticle ): ?>   
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <article id="" class="post">
                            <div class="post-image">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $relatedArticle ) ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $relatedArticle, 'post-category' ) ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <h3 class="post-title">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $relatedArticle ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_post_title($relatedArticle) ?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>

                            <div class="post-summary">
                                <p><?php echo get_summery($relatedArticle);?></p>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: If you want a working HTML snippet as a template, you need to post your current output HTML within your question. Also, specify the version of Bootstrap you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an if/else clause for the opening tag of the `div` which contains the article, adding the desired classes (applied only to the first article - I added a counter for that) in the different versions:

```html
$category = get_post_category(); $relatedArticles = get_posts( [ 'exclude' => $post->ID, 'category' => $category->term_id, 'posts_per_page' => 3 ] ); ?>
<?php if ( count( $relatedArticles ) > 0 ): ?>
<section class="related-articles">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="text-center">
        <?php echo __( 'Related Articles' ) ?>
      </h2>
      <?php $counter = 1; ?>
      <?php foreach ( $relatedArticles as $relatedArticle ): ?>
      <?php if ( count( $relatedArticles ) >= 3 ) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
      <?php } elseif (( count( $relatedArticles ) == 2) && ($counter == 1)) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
      <?php } elseif (( count( $relatedArticles ) == 1) &&  ($counter == 1)) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      <?php } ?>
        <article id="" class="post">
          <div class="post-image">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $relatedArticle ) ?>">
              <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $relatedArticle, 'post-category' ) ?>
            </a>
          </div>

          <h3 class="post-title">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $relatedArticle ); ?>">
              <?php echo get_post_title($relatedArticle) ?>
            </a>
          </h3>

          <div class="post-summary">
            <p>
              <?php echo get_summery($relatedArticle);?>
            </p>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <?php $counter++; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: If the count is 2, only the first column must have class col-sm-offset-2, is that possible ?

Comment: i just added a counter and a check for the first foreach loop instance  - should work as desired now